# Keep running a SQL procedure while browsing elsewhere in the application

Tags: sql, oracle, spring, jakarta-ee, struts

I am facing a technical issue on a web-app development :

Here is the goal :
By clicking on a button, the user launches a SQL/Oracle procedure that takes about 5 to 10 minutes to come to an end successfully. The procedure is composed of 4 steps :

1. deleting users ...
2. deleting data ...
3. copying users ...
4. copying datas ...

While the procedure is running, the user can't launch a second one, but any other thing can be done (browsing elsewhere in the application, even shutting-down the browser). In every situation, the procedure completes in the background.

Here is the technical challenge for me :

After clicking, if any user **access** or **stay on** the launching page, I want the user to see the monitoring of the execution progressing (the 4 steps).
Thus, I've got to think about some kind of a refresh of the page when the user stays on it.

Technologies of the web-app :

- Java/Java EE, Struts, Spring, Oracle SQL9i
- **NO AJAX**

Do you have any suggestion on how to make it work ?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe launch in a background/worker thread from app side.  Have the procedures you launch in background log to a table, and your front-end can query log table for latest status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest possible approach would be to have your application submit a job using the `DBMS_JOB` package that ran the four steps in a separate session.  You could either use the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` package to instrument your code so that the front end can report on the current status or you could write to a separate log table and query that log table from the front-end.  You could prevent a second job from being submitted either by having the job acquire a user-defined lock using the `DBMS_LOCK` package (which would be more robust) or by having the front-end check to see if there was a job already submitted in the `DBA_JOBS` table.  Your front-end could then just automatically refresh the page and display the current status.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you recommend `DBMS_JOB` rather than `DBMS_SCHEDULER`? I'd think the latter would be better suited to this kind of thing, since you could create a generic job, then run it as needed, rather than creating a new job each time.

Comment: @Allan - The original poster says he's using "Oracle SQL9i" which I assume means "Oracle 9i" which didn't have the DBMS_SCHEDULER package.  If he was using a more recent version of Oracle, I'd agree that the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package would be preferred.

Comment: Many thanks ! I am searching for documentation on these Oracle possibilities and will come back for further details afterwards!

Comment: Ok, your contributions have  been very helpful ! Here are the related websites that led me to a solution : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_lock_tips.htm and http://oracle.developpez.com/guide/developpement/packages/dbms_job/. Thank you !